# Is there any way in Jenkins to trigger a downstream job based on the groovy script selection from the user

Tags: jenkins

I have the Jenkins job configured with groovy script parameterized with active choice parameters. Based on the choice of the groovy script I need to trigger the downstream job.is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on Jenkins pipeline, depending on you input parameter, to run *(or not)* sub project

```
if ( condition ) {
   build job: 'Sub_project'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can condition based on the choice, and trigger it with parameters

```
if( params.CHOICE == "condition" ){
    build job: 'triggered job name', parameters: [
        string(name: 'PARAM1', value: "value1"),
        string(name: 'PARAM2', value: params.CHOICE)
    ]
}
else if( params.CHOICE == "condition2" ){
    // do something else
}
```